# can someone tell me why I am getting 'urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found' in my python pytube script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, pytube

So I have this python pytube script to get all the streams of Youtube video

```
import sys
from pytube import YouTube

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBkr9k9WmeI'
try:
    video = YouTube(url)
except:
    print("exception caught")
    sys.exit()

streams = video.streams.order_by('itag')

for st in streams:
    print(st, end=" ")
```

but on running this script I get this error `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found` on line `streams = video.streams.order_by('itag')` where I am trying to get all the streams ordered by `itag` of video and store it in `streams`.
The URL is also correct as there is no exception caught in `video = Youtube(url)` if the url was invalid or something this line would not execute.
And also I have same code in another file in the same project folder but that script works fine and I get no error or anything. The other code is as follows:

```
def downloadYoutube(url, quality, path):
    #exception handling if the video link is valid or not
    try:
        video = YouTube(url)
    except:
        print("invalid url")
        return

    #getting the video title
    videoTitle= video.title+'.mp4'

    #getting all the atreams of video
    allStreams = video.streams.order_by('itag')

    #separately saving the progressive streams
    progrssiveStreams = allStreams.filter(progressive=True)

    # separately saving the non-progressive streams
    nonProgrossiveStreams = allStreams.filter(adaptive=True)

    # separately saving the mp4 format video streams
    mp4Streams = nonProgrossiveStreams.filter(mime_type='video/mp4')
```

This code runs perfectly. In this code I can filter streams and store it in different variables but the above code give an error. The screenshot of the error is as follows: [image: error screenshot]

can someone help me out on why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Just upgrade your pytube package and run your code again. The current version is 10.8.5

Go to your terminal and type in

```
pip install pytube --upgrade
```